# Alert on uninstalling an android app

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, uninstallation

When someone is uninstalling my app, I'd like to pop-up some kind of alert or dialog that asks the user why they are uninstalling my app -- kind of like a survey.  This way, I can determine why they are unhappy and try to improve it.

I've determined how to detect when my app is being uninstalled using the ActivityManager + getRunningTasks, however, when I try to pop-up an alert using either AlertDialog or Dialog classes, they don't seem to show up.  I am able to pop up a toast though pretty easily using the Toast class in Android.

My next attempt is going to create a system alert window -- something like this:

[How to open Alert DIalog System level in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179825/how-to-open-alert-dialog-system-level-in-android)

Is there something better though?

Thanks,
J

Comment: "Is there something better though?" -- not doing it at all. At minimum, you should retain qualified legal counsel and discuss your plans with them, in light of whatever distribution channel terms and conditions you are expected to comply with. Beyond that, bear in mind [the changes to `getRunningTasks()` in Android 5.0+](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official Android Documentation states that you can Listen if another App has been removed, but not your own:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED