# How to make Image button Visible OUTSIDE the app?

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I need the image button to be visible when the user opens another app, you know, i need it like the floating button that is visible to the user when the user opens any other app.
i have a switch button the controls if the image button is visible or not

Comment: The image button is Now visible inside the app only, but i need it to be visible OUTSIDE the app too, "as long as the switch is on"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179825/how-to-open-alert-dialog-system-level-in-android).

Essentially you need to use the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission which allows you to draw over other apps, make a custom layout file which contains the button that you want to show and use the WindowManager to insert it into the view.

Comment: great,but there is stil a Problem,  when the switch is ON, the imageButton is visible....  but when i turn it off again, the imageButton doesnt disappear .. ....although I made an if conditional on the switch state so when its OFF->it executes-> manager.removeView(view); so the imageButton should be turned off but it doesnt!

Comment: You need to persist the inflated View object and pass the same object when you want to remove it. Like this : http://pastie.org/10962229